# Functions with implicit parameters c and variants for effective parameters

Tags: c

today I was studying functions with implicit parameters in C language. Today at the course the teacher talked briefly about such functions and I don't know how to implement them. The text for the problem is:

> Consider a function with 3 implicit parameters (`int`, `float`, `double`) that returns the product of the values. Call that function with different variants for effective parameters.

Could anyone give me an example and explain me what different variants for effective parameters refers to?

Comment: Use a variety of different numbers when calling the function.

Comment: It's just poor language by the professor however it simply means that values of parameters that effectively end up being `int`, `float` and `double` respectively.  For example `1 + 1` is an `int` but `1.0 + 1` is a `float` etc.

Comment: No C function has implicit parameters.  It is possible that the only in-scope *declarations* of a function do not provide prototypes -- that is, they do not specify the numbers and types of the parameters.  In that case, however, if one of the parameters actually has type `float`, then there is no way to call that function (from that scope) that produces defined behavior.

Comment: @AhmedMasud this is what you meant ? [Code](http://prntscr.com/mq2876).